# How to do Question and answers with email notification in drupal 7

Tags: 7

To make question and answers for users, I found [Answers](https://drupal.org/project/answers) or [Question/Answer](https://drupal.org/project/question_answer) modules can be used. But these are only for flow of making questions and answers. If any user (Role: customer) asks question in that site, then that question should sent to the other users (Role: Support). Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at the Rules module?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this can be achieved using Rules module.

Also refer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463011/drupal-rules-sending-an-email-address-to-a-user-reference